# How to groupby two columns of a dataframe and convert other columns into dict with column header as key

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

**Dataframe:**

```
id      id_2    salary  title   allowance   name
0420    13.28   100000  director    No      Tom
0420    13.28   70000   developer   Yes     Sam
0110    13.12   120000  director    No      Dave
0110    13.12   75000   developer   Yes     shaun
```

Groupby id and id_2 and convert the rest of columns to dict with column header

I wrote a loop for this, I think don't think it is python way, Please let me know how to do it with pandas.

**Required output:**

```
[{
            "id": 420,
            "id_2": 13.28,
            "attributes":[
                    {   "salary": 100000,
                        "title":"director",
                        "allowance":"No",
                        "name": "Tom"
                    },
                    {   "salary": 70000,
                        "title": "developer",
                        "allowance":"Yes",
                        "name": "Sam"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
            "id": 110,
            "id_2": 13.12,
            "attributes":[
                    {   "salary": 120000,
                        "title":"director",
                        "allowance":"No",
                        "name": "Dave"
                    },
                    {   "salary": 75000,
                        "title": "developer",
                        "allowance":"Yes",
                        "name": "shaun"
                    }
                ]
            }   
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is not a one-liner pandas argument that will provide a `list` of `dicts` in the shape you're requesting.
- Use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to select the groups

  - `g` is the `tuple` that represents the values used to groupby
  - `d` is the dataframe for the groupby value, `g`
- Use [`.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate through the rows of each group

  - Returns `index` represented by the first `_`, because it's not needed
  - Returns `data`, from which the labels in `groupby_list` are dropped, then convert the remainder to a `dict` using [`.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html), and append it to the `list`, `att_list`
  - After looping through all rows of the group, assign `att_list` as the value to `group['attributes']`
- Once each group has been iterated through, append the `dict`, `group`, to `dict_list`.
- `dict_list` can be converted back to a dataframe with the following:

  - `df = pd.json_normalize(dict_list, 'attributes', meta=groupby_list)`

```py
dict_list = list()
groupby_list = ['id', 'id_2']
for g, d in df.groupby(groupby_list):
    group = dict(zip(groupby_list, g))
    att_list = list()
    for _, data in d.iterrows():
        data = data.drop(labels=groupby_list)
        att_list.append(data.to_dict())
    group['attributes'] = att_list
    dict_list.append(group)
```

### `dict_list`:

```py
[{'attributes': [{'allowance': 'No',
                  'name': 'Dave',
                  'salary': 120000,
                  'title': 'director'},
                 {'allowance': 'Yes',
                  'name': 'shaun',
                  'salary': 75000,
                  'title': 'developer'}],
  'id': 110,
  'id_2': 13.12},
 {'attributes': [{'allowance': 'No',
                  'name': 'Tom',
                  'salary': 100000,
                  'title': 'director'},
                 {'allowance': 'Yes',
                  'name': 'Sam',
                  'salary': 70000,
                  'title': 'developer'}],
  'id': 420,
  'id_2': 13.28}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.groupby(['id','id_2']).apply(lambda dd:dd.iloc[:,2:].to_dict('r'))\
    .to_frame("attributes").reset_index().to_dict('r')
```

out：

```
[{'id': 110,
  'id_2': 13.12,
  'attributes': [{'salary': 120000,
    'title': 'director',
    'allowance': 'No',
    'name': 'Dave'},
   {'salary': 75000,
    'title': 'developer',
    'allowance': 'Yes',
    'name': 'shaun'}]},
 {'id': 420,
  'id_2': 13.28,
  'attributes': [{'salary': 100000,
    'title': 'director',
    'allowance': 'No',
    'name': 'Tom'},
   {'salary': 70000,
    'title': 'developer',
    'allowance': 'Yes',
    'name': 'Sam'}]}]
```